# Don't swing your head

Tags: grammar

He was imitating the fan spinning.

He spinned/swing his head at the hypermarket.

> "Don't swing your head."
>
> "Don't spin your head."

Which word is correct?

Comment: It should be "He *swung* his head" or "He *spun* his head" - both of those verbs are irregular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends what movement of a fan he was imitating.

"Swing" is a forward-and-back movement like a pendulum.

"Spin" is a circular movement like a wheel.

I'm not sure how he could be spinning his head so I would guess it would be "swing".  Maybe you really want "nod" or "rock".

note: The past tense of "swing" and "spin" is "swung" and "spun" respectively.